# How to prevent phantom reads in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Is is possible to prevent Phantom reads, or otherwise lock on a missing row in a Postgres transaction?   For example, consider the following sequence of commands:

On connection 1:

```
CREATE TABLE weather ( city varchar(80) PRIMARY KEY );
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('a');
```

Meanwhile, on connection 2:

```
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = 'a' FOR SHARE;
INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('b');
```

And back to connection 1:

```
COMMIT;
```

And again back to connection 2:

```
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM weather;
-- Shows both rows
```

It would seem impossible for the transaction on connection 2 to succeed, because the precondition for creating row 'b' was dependent on the absence of row 'a'.   How do I prevent the second transaction from succeeding?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.11

Comment: Serialisable transactions can succeed as long as the behaviour is consistent with *some* serial ordering of those transactions, but this ordering need not have anything to do with the order in which those transactions are started or committed. In this case, it looks like you would get the same outcome if you had run transaction 2 followed by transaction 1, so I don't see any reason for a conflict.

Comment: That is true, though it doesn't get me much closer to the answer of the question.  How do I do atomic read+writes without locking down the whole DB or table?

Comment: When you say "phantom read", are you referring to the fact that the `SELECT * FROM weather` sees row `'a'`? There is no guarantee of consistency between this and the previous `SELECT` if they're not in the same transaction block.

Comment: Yes.   Transaction 2 is dependent on the absence of `'a'`.  While the first transaction can complete normally, it seems impossible for transaction 2 to complete since the premise on which it is founded is now false.

Comment: Like I said, the actual order of the commits is irrelevant. The database is "pretending" that #2 happened first, and it is able to do this because no session has observed any behaviour which is inconsistent with this sequence of events. If you had a third serialisable transaction running `SELECT * FROM weather` between the two commits, it would see `a`, but not `b`; this would rule out the possibility of #2 having come first, and #2 would fail on commit.

Comment: I agree with Nick. Transaction Isolation "Serializable" can prevent Phantom Read. Your connection 2 will never succeed

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo is there anything wrong with my answer? May be it needs more clarification?

Comment: @tair sorry I am new to Stack Overflow's UI.   I thought awarding the bounty was the same as picking your answer.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it without locking the whole table is using Postgresql's `Advisory lock` [1] mechanism:

```
-- tx 1
begin;
select pg_advisory_lock(1234);
insert/update....
commit;

-- tx 2
begin;
select pg_advisory_lock(1234);
SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = 'a' FOR SHARE;
insert/update...
commit;
```

This way you are able to do inter-transaction communication, where normal MVCC behavior is not enough. In the example `1234` is arbitrary integer with a meaning at application level. Also see [2] for more ways to work with advisory locks.

[1] http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS

[2] http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS-TABLE